# Convert excel to pdf with VBScript

Tags: excel, pdf, vbscript

I want to convert pdf to excel with vbscript but it gives me an error following is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objExcel, strExcelPath, objSheet

strExcelPath = "path\file.xlsx"

' Open specified spreadsheet and select the first worksheet.
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.WorkBooks.Open strExcelPath
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

' Modify a cell.
objSheet.Range("B8").FormulaR1C1  = [sample1]
objSheet.Range("G11").FormulaR1C1 = [sample2]
objSheet.Range("G12").FormulaR1C1 = [sample3]
objSheet.Range("B10").FormulaR1C1 = [sample4]
objSheet.Range("B11").FormulaR1C1 = [sample5]

' Save as Excel.
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "path\name.xlsx" 
' Problem in saving to pdf
objExcel.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:= "path\name.pdf", _
        Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True,_
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
```

If you find any imporovement in code also, please tell me.

Comment: On what line is the error thrown?

Comment: Can you explain error details more?

Comment: In comments where I say "Problem in saving to pdf"

Comment: Change `xlQualityStandard` to `0`

Comment: No it does not help

Comment: What type of error are you getting?  By the way, you should also change `xlTypePDF` to `0`.

Comment: It says Line, Column (21,41) Error Code 1002. `xlTypePDF` to `0` still does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case somebody else has this issue replace the:

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:= "path\name.pdf", _
        Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True,_
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

With:

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, "path\name.pdf" ,0, 1, 0,,,0
```

This way it works!

Comment: The reason you need to replace `xlTypePDF` with `0` (and for others as well) is that vbscript does not recognize VBA Object Model constants, like `xlTypePDF`. VBA automatically translates this to the enumeration value (0), but you need to specify the enumeration in vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

You better try to close excel workbook after editing and saving it. You are updating excel file, in the same time you are trying to save it as Pdf. This may cause problem.

After saving it as excel, close it and reopen it for exporting as Pdf file.

Comment: Nop. Either I am going to brake it or better run a macro before saving it from VBScript but I have to see how to pass the value of the name I want to save...

Comment: Adding full path of the file may resolve this issue. For example: C:\path\name.pdf or C:\path\name.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

My code will convert word and excel files if you drag-and-drop files on to it:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 then
    MsgBox "Please drop Word or Excel ile to conver it to PDF"

Else
    Dim iDocCount: iDocCount = 0
    Dim iXlsCount: iXlsCount = 0

    For i = 0 to WScript.Arguments.Count -1
      sFilePath = WScript.Arguments(i)
      iPos = InStrRev(sFilePath,".")
      If iPos > 0 Then
        sExt = Mid(sFilePath,iPos)
        sPdfPath = Mid(sFilePath,1,iPos) & "pdf"

        If fso.FileExists(sPdfPath) = False Then        
          If sExt = ".xlsx" Then
            ExcelToPdf sFilePath, sPdfPath
            iXlsCount = iXlsCount + 1

          ElseIf sExt = ".docx" Then
            WordToPdf sFilePath, sPdfPath
            iDocCount = iDocCount + 1
          End If          
        End If

      End If
    Next

    If iDocCount = 0 And iXlsCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Did not convert any documents"
    Else
        MsgBox "Converted " & iXlsCount & " xlsx file(s) and " & iDocCount & " docx file(s)"
    End If

End if


Sub ExcelToPdf(sFrom, sTo)
  Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  excel.ScreenUpdating = false
  excel.DisplayAlerts = false

  Set workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(sFrom)
  workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, sTo

  workbook.Close()
  excel.Quit()

  Set workbook = Nothing
  Set excel = Nothing
End Sub

Sub WordToPdf(sFrom, sTo)
  Set word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set doc = word.Documents.Open(sFrom)
  doc.Activate()
  doc.SaveAs2 sTo, 17
  doc.Close()
  word.Quit()
  Set doc= Nothing
  Set word = Nothing
End Sub
```